# Return all or specific md-menu element

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angularjs-material

I have several md-menu elements on my page. I want to select a specific element inside one of the md-menu elements.

CodePen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmQNzv

```
let q = document.getElementsByClassName('md-open-menu-container');
console.log(q)
```

This returns all the `md-open-menu-container` elements. Initially the array is empty since the md elements are created when you click on the buttons to open then. They also don't remove them self if the menu is closed.

I was hoping for a more elegant way to find the menu elements beside going through all the classes. The goal is to pass the menu element that corresponds to the clicked button and find a specific class `md-focused` in that element and remove it. If that is not possible I was hoping for a method to return all classes and I would loop through the array finding the class and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

> You can do it by accessing HTML DOM properties in javascript.

```
//check for the element with Id, then its class list then your desired class.
document.getElementById("elementId").classList.contains("yourClassName");
//then remove or add using
document.getElementById("elementId").classList.add("yourClassName");
document.getElementById("elementId").classList.remove("yourClassName");
```

Comment: That's also what I posted in the question. I was hoping for an AngularJS solution. Through scope for example.